# how to make images fit in all different screens in android ? I need images with 440x300dp,check out my screenshots

Tags: android, xml, firebase, android-recyclerview

how to make images fit in all different screens in android ? I need images with 440x300dp and I created mdpi etc folders to place images,check out my screenshots and help me to solve this one

I need images to fill match parent of width and height should be 300dp but these mdpi,hdpi ..etc not having it, I'm confused

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need `ImageView` with fixed size then just use fixed size

```
android:layout_width="440dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
```

DON'T use `layout_weight`/`weightSum` params at all, with it you won't ever achieve what you want.

and after that use `android:scaleType` param to fulfil your `View`. check out [THIS](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) visual tutorial for picking proper type

laso all your drawables should have proper ratio, e.g. `mdpi` drawable may have 440px x 300px, `hdpi` x1.5, so 660px x 450px, `xhdpi` x2 and so on. some nice tutorial about density buckets in [HERE](https://medium.com/the-pineapple-slice/a-quick-guide-on-android-density-buckets-f3b0cdb0f1fb)

Comment: so now my images will be fixed sizes according to your code then how it will be in same size in different screens?

Comment: well, "fixed size" isn't same as "being in same size"? check out how density buckets works, especially my last link, and also what exacly is [dp unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp). in short: fixed size in `dp` will have same size on all screens - on low-res `100dp` will be `100px`, on high-res will be `300px` (higher density, more pixels per inch)

Comment: one more doubt now i've created mdpi,xdpi etc folders to hold images for different screen can i leave it like that ? for should i put one drawable for all different screens? now I just fixed my width and height like your code, I didn't delete that folders

Comment: make `drawable-` folders with `mdpi`, `hdpi1, `xhdpi` etc. suffixes, then put inside every folder properly sized image (so in fact there will be few images, one per density). check out factors per density bucket (linked in answer) - `mdpi` have factor x1, so you are creating image e.g. 100px x 100px, next `hdpi` folder have x1.5 factor, so image in this folder should have 150px x 150px, `xhdpi` have factor x2, `xxhdpi` x3, `xxxhdpi` x4

Comment: Thank you bro already I created folders that you can see in my ss ..is that right? now i need to place images according to it ,

Comment: exacly, all folders looks like properly named, just put properly sized images in every bucket and you are good to go (set for `ImageView`, add `scaleType`)

Comment: Bro I forgot to tell you one thing now I'm going to retrieve images from firebase, now all folders mdpi,xdpi will be empty because all images will be in firebase, shall I leave that folders ? or Should I create separate json column for mdpi,hdpi etc images?

Comment: best option for app would be to get links to different images (resized) and app should pick proper one - if `mdpi` then gets low-res image, if `xxhdpi` then picks some high-res.

Comment: you can also shorten a bit this mechanism, e.g. two links to hi-res and low-res images, devices below `xhdpi` pick first one, all other second one. yet another approach is one link to one hi-res image and scale it down after downloading to fit device screen properly - but this is power-and-time-cost (conversion/resize), not so efficient, and still very old device may have problems with bigger bitmaps e.g. 1500px x 1500px, at the same time another flagship device may have UHD display and 1500x1500 resolution isn't scary/too much for shure

Comment: so now what i've to do for example i have demo image with 440x300dp

Comment: `dp` or `px`? put link to 880px x 600px as `lowResUrl` (`xhdpi`, factor x2) and 1760px x 1200px as `hiResUrl` (`xxxhdpi`, factor x4). use `lowResUrl` on `xhdpi` and lower only, for `xxhdpi` and higher (xxx, but also maybe some next in future) use `hiResUrl`. `Bitmap`s below 1000px in any dimensions can by handled by every device, even oldest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225315/discussion-between-madhanmohan-and-snachmsm).

Comment: sadly I'm not your personal trainer, I don't have time to explain to you all the things related to images/densities/possibilities etc. I've already answered your question, my job is done here. If you have any other question feel free to make new topic/question